# Compiling Coffeescript with Flask in Production

Tags: python, coffeescript, flask, dev-to-production

I have a Flask app that I'm running in production.  Right now it has a big ugly js file that I'd like to break out and rewrite in something like Coffeescript.  I was considering something like [Flask-Cake](http://flask-cake.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to simplify the CoffeeScript compilation.  However, I don't know how something like that would work for production.  I should probably have a script that compiles the coffeescript files before deploying, right?  I've never worked on a system with this particular layout -- uncompiled server-side but compiled client-side.  What's the standard procedure here?

Answer (score 8):

You are probably looking for [Flask-Assets](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/flask-assets/).

Example from the website:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle

app = Flask(__name__)
assets = Environment(app)

js = Bundle('jquery.js', 'base.js', 'widgets.js',
            filters='jsmin', output='gen/packed.js')
assets.register('js_all', js)
```

This would automatically concatenate `jquery.js`, `base.js` and `widgets.js` in your `static` folder, pipe them through `jsmin` and save the result in `static/gen/packed.js`.

This compilation is by default always happening when one of the source files changes. Watching the files in production is kinda expensive in production (and would require a coffeescript compiler to be installed on the server!), so there is a configuration value to disable the monitoring.

Another plugin that is more lightweight, but in my experience also less powerful is [Flask-Makestatic](https://github.com/DasIch/Flask-MakeStatic).

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at [DukPy](https://github.com/amol-/dukpy)!** It's a simple javascript interpreter for Python and can compile `CoffeeScript`, `TypeScript`, `BabelJS` and `JSX`. Usage is very simple:

```py
import dukpy

dukpy.coffee_compile("CoffeeScript goes here!")
```

DukPy is the successor to the [Python-CoffeeScript](https://github.com/doloopwhile/Python-CoffeeScript) package witch is no longer maintained.